# Kubernetes OIDC: Groups are ignored?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

currently I’m trying to get the the api server connected with my keycloak.

When I use the oidc-information from the user everything works fine, but the groups seem to be ignored
The apiserver is running with the parameter

```
     --oidc-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
     --oidc-client-id=kubernetes
     --oidc-groups-claim=groups
     --oidc-groups-prefix=oidc:
     --oidc-issuer-url=https://keycloak.example.com/auth/realms/master
     --oidc-username-claim=preferred_username
     --oidc-username-prefix=oidc:
```

I added a ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: developer-role
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["namespaces","pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: developer-crb
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: developer-role
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: "oidc:myuser"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

and for my user “myuser” everythin works fine.

But when I change the ClusterRoleBinding to subjet Group

```
....
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: "oidc:group1"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
...
```

I receive forbidden.

I tried to debug the jwt token and the group seems to be included:

```
{
...
  "groups": [
    "group1",
    "group2",
    "group3"
  ],
...
}
```

Any ideas why my groups are ignored/my ClusterRoleBinding not working?

Comment: Could you solve the problem? I have a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64677173/kubernetes-oidc-no-valid-group-mapping/64750511#64750511).

Answer (score 2):

```
....
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: "oidc:group1"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
...
```

should be:

```
....
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: "oidc:group1"
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
...
```

Comment: I have a similar problem as the thread creator, can you please help in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64677173/kubernetes-oidc-no-valid-group-mapping/64750511#64750511)?