# Kubernetes OIDC: No valid group mapping

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, openid-connect, kube-apiserver

I have the problem that I can log on to my dashboard via OIDC, but then the oidc group information is not mapped correctly and I cannot access the corresponding resources.

**Basic setup**

- K8s version: 1.19.0
- K8s setup: 1 master + 2 worker nodes
- Based on Debian 10 VMs
- CNI: Calico
- [Louketo Proxy](https://github.com/louketo/louketo-proxy) as OIDC proxy
- OIDC: Keycloak Server (Keycloak X [Quarkus])

**Configurations**

I have configured the K8s apiserver with these parameters.

*kube-apiserver.yaml*

```
- --oidc-issuer-url=https://test.test.com/auth/realms/Test
- --oidc-client-id=test
- --oidc-username-claim=preferred_username
- --oidc-username-prefix="oidc:"
- --oidc-groups-claim=groups
- --oidc-groups-prefix="oidc:"
```

*ClusterRoleBinding*

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: "test-cluster-admin"
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: "Test"
```

I used the following louketo parameters

*Louketo Proxy*

```
/usr/bin/louketo-proxy --discovery-url=$OIDC_DISCOVERY_URL --client-id=$OIDC_CLIENT_ID --client-secret=$OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET  -listen=$OIDC_LISTEN_URL --encryption-key=$OIDC_ENCRYPTION_KEY --redirection-url=$OIDC_REDIRECTION_KEY --enable-refresh-tokens=true --upstream-url=$OIDC_UPSTREAM_URL --enable-metrics
```

I get the following error message inside the dashboard.
*K8s error*

```
replicasets.apps is forbidden: User "\"oidc:\"<user_name>" cannot list resource "replicasets" in API group "apps" in the namespace "default"
```

I hope you can help me with this problem, I already tried most of the manuals from the internet, but haven't found a solution yet.

PS: I have done the corresponding group mapping in the Keycloak server and also validated that the group entry is transferred.

Comment: Does your oidc `ServiceAccount` has a proper `ClusterRole` and `ClusterRoleBinding` setup?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor What do you mean with OIDC Service Account?

Comment: The one behind `"\"oidc:\"<user_name>"`. I am trying to get to the bottom of the issue before I'll be able to post a meaningful answer.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I haven't created a K8s service account with the credentials of the OIDC user. I can confirm that a `ClusterRoleBinding`, the `ClusterRole` and the OIDC user exist. The role that I use is the default admin role of the K8s cluster (cluster-admin). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how I could solve the problem?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing the same challenge as I did and you want to integrate Keycloak into your K8s cluster, share the dashboard and connect it to Keycloak, you can find my configuration below. Within my cluster I use the Louketo Proxy as interface between Kubernetes and Keycloak. The corresponding configuration of the deployment is not included in this post.

**Keycloak**

I want to start with the configuration of Keycloak. In the first step I created a corresponding client with the following settings.
[image: Keycloak client configuration]

After that I created the two group membership and audience (needed by the louketo proxy) mappers.
[image: Keycloak kubernetes mappers]

The exact settings of the mappers can be taken from the two images.

**Group membership mapping**

[image: Group membership mapping]
**Audience mapping**

[image: Audience mapping]

**Kubernetes**

In the second step I had to update the api server manifest and create the `RoleBinding` and `ClusterRoleBinding` within the Kubernetes cluster.

**Api server manifest** *(`default path: /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`)*

```
- --oidc-issuer-url=https://test.test.com/auth/realms/Test
- --oidc-client-id=test
- --oidc-username-claim=preferred_username
- --oidc-username-prefix="oidc:"
- --oidc-groups-claim=groups
- --oidc-groups-prefix="oidc:"
```

**RoleBinding**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: "test"
  namespace: "kubernetes-dashboard"
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: "\"oidc:\"Test"
  namespace: "kube-system"
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
```

**ClusterRoleBinding**

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: "test"
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Group
  name: "\"oidc:\"Test"
```

*@Community I hope I can help you with this configuration. If you have any questions, feel free to ask me.*

Comment: are you sure your indentation is correct? Your ClusterRoleBinding has 2 top-level fields with the name "name"

Comment: @Benni No, there was a mistake inside the indentation. I've fixed it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a community wiki answer aimed to approach the issue from the Kubernetes side. Any one familiar with the possible Keycloak group/role mapping solution feel free to edit it.**

The error you see means that the service account for OIDC doesn't have the proper privileges to list `replicasets` in the default namespace. The easiest way out of it would be to simply setup the [ServiceAccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/), [ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrole-example) and [ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#clusterrolebinding-example) from scratch and make sure it has the proper privileges. For example, you can create a `clusterrolebinding` with permissions “admin” [by executing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-clusterrolebinding-em-):

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding OIDCrolebinding - -clusterrole=admin - - group=system:serviceaccounts:OIDC
```

The same [can be done](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-clusterrole-em-) for the `ClusterRole`:

```
kubectl create clusterrole OIDC --verb=get,list,watch --resource=replicasets --namespace=default
```

More examples of how to use the `kubectl create` in this scenario can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#kubectl-create-clusterrole).

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) you can find a whole official guide regarding the RBAC Authorization.

EDIT:

Also, please also check if your `ClusterRoleBinding` for the `"\"oidc:\"<user_name>"` is in the `"default"` namespace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. **But first of all I don't understand which service account I should create/use and secondly how the role mapping from the OIDC group to the K8s group should work?** The exemplary error is not the only missing permission issue. I rather think there is a problem with the actual mapping of the groups, maybe even because my oidc group is called "Test" and only lower case groups are possible.

Comment: I tried to approach your issue from the K8s side. I'm sorry it is was not enough. Unfortunately, I am not too much familiar with Keycloak's concepts but in order to eliminate the group mapping issue I would start from checking [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/groups.html) and [here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#user-role-mappings). I will edit my answer and change it to community wiki as it does not approach the whole issue.

Comment: Thanks for your support. What exactly do you mean, which service account do I have to create? I can definitely say that the group is included in the token. I would like to know what exactly an OIDC Group Mapping could look like? Could johnharris85 possibly help me with this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Have you managed to make it work? If not, please also check if your `ClusterRoleBinding` for the `"\"oidc:\"<user_name>"` is in the "default" namespace. As I said, I am not sure how the mapping should look like but I want to make sure that the k8s components are fine to better narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint concerning the `ClusterRoleBinding`. I have checked all settings again and could find the error. I will post my complete configuration in the next days.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful. You can write down what was the actual problem in the comments so I could edit or rewrite my answer. It would be way more clear for the rest of the community (no need to go through a ton of our comments) and would also properly close this topic.

Comment: The main problem was the oidc mapping. I thought the prefix command (`--oidc-groups-prefix="oidc:"`) inside the api manifest allows you to define only the group inside the `ClusterRoleBinding` and not to specify the prefix (`"\"oidc:\"<user_name>"`) again. Furthermore, I made the mistake that I did not format the prefix correctly within the `ClusterRoleBinding`. I will publish my complete configuration (Kubernetes + Keycloak) within this post and hope that I can help other users of the community.